# Laravel 6:0 Trying to Retrieve Corresponding Product Data When Clicking on Product

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a videogame store. I have my 4 categories (playstation, xbox, nintendo, pc). Each category view and controller retrieves the product details from a MySQL database. On each category page, 12 products are retrieved with their corresponding name, image and price. Here is the logic that enables this functionality (just for context, this isn't what I want to do with the other pages):

```
// playstation.blade.php
@section('content')
    @if(isset($playstationGames))
        @foreach($playstationGames as $playstationGame)
            <h2>{{ $playstationGame->name }}</h2>
            <a href="{{ $playstationGame->slug }}"><img src="{{ asset($playstationGame->image) }}" alt="playstationgame"></a>
            <h4>{{ $playstationGame->price }}</h4>
        @endforeach 
    @endif
@endsection
```

This is the error I get when trying to get product details according to the slug in my database that matches my slug in my GET query URL: `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

Here's the code for that:

```
// PlaystationController.php
public function show($slug)
    {   
        $game = Game::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        return view('products.game')->with([
            'game' => $game
        ]);
    }
```

When I click on one of the images, I want to be directed to a page for that product. For example, if I click on the image for Mario Kart, I want to be directed to a page with the data for that game (corresponding image, name, price, description). These details are already in the database. I know how to fetch these as an array. But I want to fetch these individually and for each one to correspond to the page (slug) I'm visiting.

How can I achieve this?

Here's an example of what I want: https://laravelecommerceexample.ca/shop

When you click on the image for 'laptop 1', you are taken to it's corresponding 'slug page' (I've already achieved this). What I don't know how to do is return the unique description, price, image etc as displayed when you click on the product image on this website. All I've managed to do is return my blade template from my slug link.

As you can see in the above code. I know how to loop through the products and return them all. I don't know how to return one that matches the corresponding slug of the page.

Yesterday, I thought I solved my problem. Here's how I thought I fixed it:

Instead of:

```
Game::create([
            'slug' => 'playstation/alien-isolation',
            'platform' => 'playstation',
            'name' => 'Alien Isolation', 
            'price' => '£19.99', 
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt debitis, amet magnam accusamus nisi distinctio eveniet ullam. Facere, cumque architecto.',
            'image' => '/storage/images/playstation/alien_isolation.jpeg'
        ]);
```

I used the slug method:

```
Game::create([
            'slug' => Str::slug('Alien Isolation', '-'),
            'platform' => 'playstation',
            'name' => 'Alien Isolation', 
            'price' => '£19.99', 
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt debitis, amet magnam accusamus nisi distinctio eveniet ullam. Facere, cumque architecto.',
            'image' => '/storage/images/playstation/alien_isolation.jpeg'
        ]);
```

This worked while I had this in my controller:

```
public function show($slug)
    {   
        $game = Game::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        return view('products.game')->with([
            'game' => $game
        ]);
    }
```

and this in my web.php:

```
Route::get('/playstation/{slug}', 'PlaystationController@show');
```

By 'worked', I mean it returned the data according to the corresponding slug of the page and the slug in the database. Unfortunately, as soon as I refresh the page, I get a 404.

This makes absolutely no sense to me but I am new to this.

I also don't understand how this can possibly work at all when I run my data dump method and get a response of 'null':

```
$game = Game::where('slug', $slug)->first();
dd($game);
```

Why would I be getting a 404 but only after refreshing the page? There are so many things I'm confused about here. Does anyone know how to solve my problem and why I'm not succeeding here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Str::slug helper

You need to add /playstation in your href

```
<a href="/playstation/{{ $playstationGame->slug }}"><img src="{{ asset($playstationGame->image) }}" alt="playstationgame"></a>
```

also try to change your controller to compact

```
public function show($slug)
    {   
        $game = Game::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        return view('products.game', compact('game'));
    }
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks! Why is using the 'compact' method more desirable?

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves compact creates an array containing variables and their values. its more like view('viewName', ['game'=> $game])

Comment: OK thanks. So it serves the same purpose but it's more concise.